# How to customize style from spinner dropdown CHOICES?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-xml, android-spinner

I can customize the background of the selected option on a spinner dropdown using:

```
<item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/customSpinner</item>
<style name="customSpinner" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
<item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
<item name="android:background">#000000</item>
</style>
```

But I can't manage to change the background and textcolor of the list of options that the dropdown has. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner);
```

custom_spinner.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  parent="@android:style/TextAppearance_Widget_DropDownItem"
  android:textColor="#988767"
>
</TextView>
```

Comment: thanks but I would like to use the default android style, just want to change the textcolor. How can i achieve that?

Comment: make a custom style that inherits the android style you want and override the textColor attribute

Comment: @DavidMarmoy but I just can't find the Android style that is reponsible for the dropdown list options. The selected option is the android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.DropDownItem.Spinner. But it isn't the one for the other available options.

Comment: I have update the answer for you. However this has not been tested, it should point you in the right direction

Comment: sorry, I should have read your question more thoroughly, I can see you already know how to do that. So, are you looking for the name of the style to inherit from for the textview in the above answer? I don't know the name of that, but a hack might be to go through the android sdk folder and navigate to the drawables, where you can find the ninepatch they use for the android spinner items. Then you can use the above adapter.setDropDownViewResource, with a custom textview where you've set the background to that ninepatch. This is just off the top of my head, I'm sure you can find a better way.