# Custom spinner like android 4.0

Tags: android, spinner

I try to make custom spinner looks like in android 4.0, but I dont know how to replase sprinner dropdown selection list. Any help is welcome.

I get resource files from android 4.0 sdk, but dopdown selection list does not change.

```
<Spinner
       android:id="@+id/update_frequency_spinner"
       android:layout_width="75dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:spinnerMode="dropdown" 

       android:background="@drawable/spinner_background_holo_light"
       android:dropDownSelector="@drawable/list_selector_holo_light"
       android:popupBackground="@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_holo_light">
</Spinner>
```

Answer (score 1):

- This [How to customize style from spinner dropdown CHOICES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077767/how-to-customize-style-from-spinner-dropdown-choices) may answer your question.
- You could also look into using HoloEverywhere if you want a holo-themed app for pre holo devices https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere